# Can I work with two polygons that were created in a different CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have created two square polygons each having an area of roughly 5.000ha. One of the polygons is located in Australia and the other one in Iceland, because I am working with relatively large areas which are located in different regions of the world I have created each polygon in a different CRS. I have used WGS 84 / UTM zone 26N and WGS 84 / UTM zone 54N. I want to work with both polygons in one project. What is the best way to do this? Will it work if I reproject both of them to for instance WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator?

Comment: Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'on the fly' CRS transformation allows you to handle layers with different CRS without having to manually change their CRS !

Comment: The on the fly will visually reproject them to the projects CRS, right? If I would reproject all of them to the same CRS will it then also mean that I can reproject all of them to the same CRS?

Comment: You don't need to reproject manually them since you already set up the right projection to each of your layer. When you will add both of your layers using the 'on the fly' CRS transformation in your empty QGIS canvas, it will list you several CRS transformations to reproject them automatically in the canvas. If you edit those layers and save them they will keep their initial CRS